# How to find last ordered user in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables "users" and "orders".

Users:

```
userid   apartment_id   blockid  flat_id
1002             2           3       101
1004             1           4       102 
1005             2           3       101
```

Orders:

```
orderid   userid   order_date
10         1002    2020-07-11
11         1004    2020-08-13  
12         1005    2020-09-11
```

Now I want the following:

```
apartment_id    blockid    flat_id   no_of_users  last_order_date   last_order_user_id
    2              3         101        2            2020-09-11          1005
```

I have written the SQL for finding all these except for "last_order_user_id". Can someone please help me with this? This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT apartment_id,blockid,flat_id,COUNT(DISTINCT u.userid) AS users,MAX(o.order_date) AS Last_order_on FROM users u LEFT JOIN orders o ON u.user_id=o.user_id GROUP BY apartment_id,blockid,flat_no;
```

I have tried adding o.userid to the field list in select statement but as the orders table is ordered by order_date in ascending order it is returning the first ordered user id.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out the maximum order date for each apartment/block/flat combination; then you can join that back to the orders and users tables to find the user who made the last order:

```
SELECT u.apartment_id, u.blockid, u.flat_id,
       m.no_of_users,       
       m.last_order_date,
       u.user_id AS last_order_user_id
FROM users u 
JOIN orders o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
JOIN (
  SELECT apartment_id, blockid, flat_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) AS no_of_users,
         MAX(o.order_date) AS last_order_date
  FROM users u
  JOIN orders o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
  GROUP BY apartment_id, blockid, flat_id
) m ON m.apartment_id = u.apartment_id
   AND m.blockid = u.blockid
   AND m.flat_id = u.flat_id
   AND m.last_order_date = o.order_date
```

Output:

```
apartment_id    blockid     flat_id     no_of_users     last_order_date     last_order_user_id
1               4           102         1               2020-08-13          1004
2               3           101         2               2020-09-11          1005
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f38a1a/14)